# OnChange Action in DropDown in Data Grid

Tags: zappdev

I have a Bound Table (to a collection in my Model)

One of its cells is a Drop Down, getting its values from a Dataset.

I want to create a Controller Action, to be called on the "OnChange" action of the DropDown, that will display me the selected value. Example:

```
ShowMessage(selectedDropDownItem.Value);
```

Is this possible? If yes, how? (I don't even know how to write the Controller Action.. What would be its input??)

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are inside a Bound Table, you should pass to the Controller Action the row that the Dropdown that changed is in.

Lets assume that your Table (named `CustomerTable`) is bound to `Model.Customers` of type `Domain.Customer`

Your Controller Action should have a parameter of the Bound Table type (`Domain.Customer`), and at the OnChange event you should pass the current row instance: `CustomerTable_CurrentItem`